# netcat and tee redirection via a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, netcat

Quick question that has been haunting me all day.. 
I have a bash script that includes this line:

```
nc -l 8044 | tee nc-output &
```

The output from netcat is never being written to nc-output. 
If I run that line outside of the bash script, it works.

```
nc -l 8044 > afile &
```

Also does not work, but works outside a bash script.

I need the ampersand there so I can run the process separately and continuing executing my batch script. Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that comes to mind: does your script have a different working directory than you expect?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The script is creating an empty file on each run.. just nothing written to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as soon as nc accepts a connection it will try to read from stdin.
When you run this as a bash script it will always read EOF immediately and close the connection, what doesn't happen when you run it outside a script.

Use `-d` switch to prevent nc from read from stdin.

```
nc -d -l 8044 > afile &
```

Comment: I will give this a try get back to you! Thanks!